# Comparing between cleavage of ethers

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, ethers

We have to find out which ether would undergo cleavage faster.[image]

**My Attempt**

IV. I couldn't figure out, so i carried out simple SN1 cleavage. Since +M effect of OH > OCH3  1st reactant seemed  right answer. But I am wrong. Why and what would be process?

V. I believe since there are no 3° Carbon, so process of cleavage should be SN2. The answer comes out right, but is my analysis right?

Please help.

Comment: (Nitpick: Tell you teacher we´re now in the 21st century, not the first half of the 20th. It´s called a *tertiary* carbon atom.)

Comment: The first example has an ether, but that's misleading. You're trying to cleave a hemiacetal/acetal. But given that it's cyclic, I'm not even sure what the question is asking, since it's likely that no matter what the conditions are, then equilibrium will favor the closed form. In (V), you need to look how the ether will be hydrolyzed. That requires understanding that the second one is a vinyl ether and has other modes of reactivity with acid.

Comment: Zhe i think they are not much concerned about the reaction of double bond. In solution they have simply written acetals are more reactive and less stable. But can u tell why?

Comment: *eyeroll* This is for understanding how mesomeric stabilisation affects reactivity of acetals and vinyl ethers. More precisely, that oxocarbenium ions are *very* stable in comparison with carbocations.

Comment: The NCERT Book of class 12 demonstrates this well. Read it.

Comment: No, there are _precisely_ concerned with the location double bond because that's the difference in reactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**I found this answer for IV**

**And in V-B is formed because it is more conjugated**